# Why does it take O(n!) time to specify a canonical ordering for learning flatten adjacency matrices/graphs?

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, machine-learning, runtime-analysis, graph-traversal

I was reading a paper for learning graphs (paper is [GraphRNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08773)) and it says in section 2.2 (emphasis by me):

> Vector-representation based models. One naive approach would be to represent G by flattening $A^π$ into a vector in $R^{n^2}$, which is then used as input to any off-the-shelf generative model, such as a VAE or GAN. However, this approach suffers from serious drawbacks: it cannot naturally generalize to graphs of varying size, and requires training on all possible node permutations or **specifying a canonical permutation,both of which require O(n!) time in general**

I understand how flattening the adjacency matrix would require the algorithm to receive all possible orderings and thus it takes $O(n!)$ to learn it - but I don't understand why specifying a canonical ordering has that issue to. With some abuse of notation just do $\pi(G,A) = G^\pi,A^\pi$ for all graphs before giving them to the training algorithm. Something like (say we have $N$ graphs with $n$ verticies and we loop T times):

```
for t in T
  for G,A in Graphs.Dataset
      Gpi, Api = pi(G,A)  # takes worst case O(n^2) to at least do print the adj matrix
      y = mdl(Gpi, Api)
      loss(y,Gpi,Api).backward().sgd() # assume we are doing SGD or something
```

The run time seems $O(N)*O(n^2)$ not $O(N)*O(n!)$. So I am not sure why the canonical representation takes $O(n!)$ (note I am aware that just multiplying big-Os like that can lead to problems but specifying the summation explicitly in this case I think leads to no issues).

Thanks for the help!

---

cross:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/nxjs1t/why_does_it_take_on_time_to_specify_a_canonical/
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Why-does-it-take-O-n-time-to-specify-a-canonical-ordering-for-learning-flatten-adjacency-matrices-graphs

Comment: can you clarify `canonical order` here? do you mean for example the order by the vertex degrees or something else?

Comment: A "canonical permutation" in the sense of the authors would accept an adjacency matrix $A$, and return a permutation $\pi_A$, so that two adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ represent the same underlying undirected graph if and only if $\pi_A(A) = \pi_B(B)$. In particular this could be used to solve the graph isomorphism problem, which is known to be hard (but not factorially-hard...)

Answer (score 1):

If we had a way to canonicalize graphs efficiently, then we could canonicalize the graph before feeding it to the ML.

Unfortunately, no polynomial-time algorithm for [graph canonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization) is known.  One naive algorithm for graph canonization runs in $O(n!)$ time.  I don't believe the claim is literally correct that graph canonization requires $O(n!)$ time, but a plausible conjecture is that there is no polynomial-time algorithm for graph canonization.  I suspect that's what that quote is trying to express.